# If you were to "design" an ocean planet for life, what would you do?

Tags: science-based

I understand that a larger ocean planet (or waterworld) will have an ocean less deep that a smaller one since pressures get higher faster as you go deeper (transition to ice VII). Assuming my planet has active volcanism due to residual heat and radioactive material in the core, I would hope that rocky material could "break through" the ice VII and produce underwater mountains. I also would like to add contributing material from asteroid/comet bombardment from space.

Could there be a plausible scenario for life starting in such a situation or would the water/rock interface be under such high pressure that this would be unlikely?

What about panspermia life from a "doomed" planet in the same system that could build floating islands of biomass? And what about the crazy winds and waves. Would they come to an equilibrium and be tolerable for lifeforms??

Comment: Please, avoid questions  about "you".  Each peron would answer it  differently, and each answer would be good for that particular user. Also,  I see 3 quite distinct questions here:  Life  starting deep, panspermia, and  wind    waves  tolerable for lifeforms.  One question per question is a  rule  here, so post them separately. Of course, you would need to add some details  for   2nd and 3rd  to be  answerable.

Comment: I would rather start with a question like "How DNA-based life can emerge on an ocean planet"?

Comment: Since life on Earth started in the oceans and then transitioned to the land, how is this scenario any different from Earth sans land?

Comment: @Muuski there are theories that life actually started in shallow areas, where wind and waves mixed stuff, but there was no flow enough to dilute stuff before interesting things happened. As far as I know (and I don't know much) this is the most promising theory.

Comment: @Muuski .. The type of "waterworld" or "ocean planet" I am talking about is nothing like early Earth. It is a lower density planet type that is believed to exist (ie. Gliese 1214b https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gliese_1214_b ), where the "ocean" just gets deeper and deeper until high pressures cause a transition to a dense state of water called ice VII. I apologize to this stack exchange (this is my first question here). I know this question wouldn't fly on Astronomy Stack Exchange. I thought the Worldbuilding one would be different. I guess I need to get more specific.

Comment: @Jack R. Woods Oh, that's interesting! I wonder what the temperatures are like on an ocean planet.